# How to make Spock @Issue annotation render in damage control reports?

Tags: spock, issue-tracking

The Spock testing framework has the [Damage Control](https://github.com/damage-control/report) plugin that generates nice reports for your tests, and Spock has the [`spock.lang.Issue`](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/javadoc/latest/spock/lang/Issue.html) annotation, which:

> Indicates that a feature method or specification relates to one or more issues in an external issue tracking system

It seems a no-brainer that the damage control report should be able to render the link in its report, but I can not figure out to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the @Issue annotation is currently unused. Either you ask the writers of Damage control to implement what you ask or you implement it yourself and send them a pull request :-)